# How to pass multiple parameters not in the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Currently the form data is passed via the URL, like below.

```
document.getElementById('newChildForm').action = "./populateImageProcessing?personId="+ temp+ "&category="+ strUser+ "&fromDate="+ frmDate+ "&toDate=" + toDate+"&advFromDayID="+advFromDayID+"&advFromMonthID="+advFromMonthID+"&advFromYearID="+advFromYearID+"&advToDayID="+advToDayID+"&advToMonthID="+advToMonthID+"&advToYearID="+advToYearID;

document.getElementById('newChildForm').submit();
```

**I want to pass the form data separately, and not via the URL.**

I tried the below with ajax/jQuery

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url : "./populateImageProcessing",
        type : "POST",
        data : "personId=" + temp + "&category="
                    + strUser
                    + "&fromDate="+ frmDate+ "&toDate=" + toDate+ "&advFromDayID="+advFromDayID+"&advFromMonthID="+advFromMonthID+"&advFromYearID="+advFromYearID+"&advToDayID="+advToDayID
                    +"&advToMonthID="+advToMonthID+"&advToYearID="+advToYearID,
success: function(data){
$("#newChildForm").html(data); 
}
 });
```

The jQuery working in SIT environment, but I've some trouble in UAT environment due to CSP.

Is there any way could use plain javascript `document.getElementById('newChildForm').action="./populateImageProcessing"`, and pass the parameters separately, and not in the URL.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly does CSP have to do with this? If you don’t want the parameters in the URL, then POST is really the only viable option; but we don’t even know whether your server-side component wants to accept POST data. The alternative to creating that URL in such an ugly way as it is done in the first code snippet, would be to fill hidden form fields with the values, and then submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code :

```
var data = "personId=" + temp + "&category="+ strUser+ "&fromDate="+ frmDate+ "&toDate=" + toDate+ "&advFromDayID="+advFromDayID+"&advFromMonthID="+advFromMonthID+"&advFromYearID="+advFromYearID+"&advToDayID="+advToDayID+"&advToMonthID="+advToMonthID+"&advToYearID="+advToYearID;

var xhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.open("POST", "populateImageProcessing", true);

xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('newChildForm').innerHTML = this.responseText
       }
    };

xhttp.send(data);
```

Comment: I tried this, but the data is not displayed. I thought maybe I should submit the form, so I followed up your part with this: document.getElementById('newChildForm').submit();

It throws 404 error. But, if I click on the browser back button, results are displayed.

I would prefer the results are displayed upon clicking the search button.

Comment: I guess , the problem is in **populateImageProcessing** file.

Comment: Check redirects in populateImageProcessing file and are you sure that url  without file type ( Like .php or .asp ) is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this ?
Json is a good way to pass multiple parameters.

```
var obj = { personId: temp, category: strUser, fromDate: frmDate, toDate: toDate, advFromDayID :advFromDayID, advFromMonthID: advFromMonthID, advFromYearID: advFromYearID, advToDayID: advToDayID, advToMonthID: advToMonthID, advToYearID: advToYearID };
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "./populateImageProcessing",
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $("#newChildForm").html(data); 
    }
});
```

But I don't know if you can handle it on the "server" side ?
Tell me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'm hoping to avoid jQuery/ Ajax. If I could submit the form, and not pass the parameters in the URL, that would be very helpful